# Postgres archiving not running

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, write-ahead-logging, archive-log

I am using logical replication. Currently I am using stored procedure to pump 3K data per hour to see if the WAL files increase. It does increase by 1 file every 12k records. But the WAL archiving is not running even though I have set it ON.

Here is my setting :

```
wal_level : Logical
wal_log_hints : ON 
wal_keep_segments : 0   
Hot_standby : ON
archive_command : cp  %p /Archive%f
archive_mode : ON
max_wal_size : 1 GB    
min_wal_size : 2 GB    
checkpoint_timeout : 300 s    
checkpoint_flush_after : 32 8kB unit    
wal_sync_method : fdatasync    
fsync : ON
```

Then I run : `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_archiver;`. The result is below :

```
Name              |Value                        |
------------------+-----------------------------+
archived_count    |0                            |
last_archived_wal |                             |
last_archived_time|                             |
failed_count      |33552                        |
last_failed_wal   |00000001000000960000002C     |
last_failed_time  |2022-08-03 15:07:54.849 +0700|
stats_reset       |2022-06-30 13:46:05.298 +0700|
```

I don't see anything from the /Archive directory either, its simply empty.

What should I do to make the archiving running ? How can I make sure that the archiving is running, what parameters do I have to monitor ?

I am using Postgres 12, Ubuntu 12.11

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the Postgres log file?

Comment: ok thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, i will check. then what do I have to look for in the log file ?

Comment: /Archive%f does not indicate a directory, but rather a file in the disk root.

Comment: @jjanes So, whats the correct one then ? I read it from here : https://orahow.com/enable-disable-archive-mode-in-postgres and also here ""archive_command='cp %p /Archive/Location/%f'"  it says "archive_command='cp %p /Archive/Location/%f'". Isn't what I set meant "give prefix 'Archive' for every file" ?

Comment: "Isn't what I set meant "give prefix 'Archive' for every file" Yes, but why would you want to give a prefix to every file?  And it then tries to write the file to the root directory, which you hopefully don't have permissions to write to.  If you want to write them into a *directory* named /Archive, you need another slash, like `/Archive/%f`

Comment: Yes jjanes. Thank you for pointing it out. It works now.